# Classification system for healthcare facilities based on most common procedures

Tags: data-request, medical, classification

I work for a Health Insurer and need to map facilities (in this case they would be Ambulatory Surgical Centers) to a handful of yet to be defined categories (e.g. Ear Nose & Throat, Gastroenterology, etc.) based on the types of procedures most commonly done at the facility (this would be identified in their claims data).

At this point the best grouping I have is the Clinical Classification Software (CCS) grouping, but that has about 250 categories and I need a system that gives me closer to 5-10 categories.

Has anyone done or seen anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Check out http://xpresso.abzooba.com/XpressoOnWeb/.

They have built up so many domains already (health care - armamentarium) is one of them. They have fixed aspects (usually 5-6) for every domain. and the engine does aspect based sentiment analysis. Try out a few sample sentences in that link.

Note: You'll have to create an account, but it is open data.

Comment: The user above is spamming this link and using at least 2 accounts to comment back and forth as a sort of "social proof".  See posts from Keeth and Potter.

Comment: False accusations.